# Document ID in SharePoint Online not working

Tags: configuration, office365, sharepoint-online

I need permanent links inside my SharePoint Online. 
To get permanent links, I have enabled the Document-ID Feature on the SiteCollection Level and configured Document ID Settings.
I have checked the checkbox to update the document ID in the settings also.

After some time of waiting I neither see any SiteCollection column for Document-ID nor I see a DocumentID Column in my Document Libraries.
After doing some research, I have found an article, saying I have to check update all content types during next refresh in the Content Type publishing hub.
But still - I don't see Document-ID.

What could be the solution to get Document ID in my Libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.
After recreating all the document IDs in SharePoint, I just had to add the column in the default view. After this, the document Id was visible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that SharePoint Online now does unique identifiers by default without having to enable that feature.  There's a copy link menu item in the item's context menu and the url contains a docid in the query string.  The url remains the same even if you move the document to another location.

Answer (score 0):

Under the SharePoint document library. Under view, click on Edit current view and you will find the document id option there. However if you have just enabled the feature and you will look for the document id under edit current view. It's hard to find because this option take atleast an hour to appear there.